# Input function of type `:: IO a`

Tags: haskell

The only "user input" functions I know of in the Prelude return `String`s - but often (I'd say more frequently) we want to read numbers or other types.

Is there a function of type `:: IO a` or similar, for reading a value of arbitrary type? I've [searched hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3A%3A+IO+a) for such a function, but either due to it not existing or due to the large number of other functions of similar type, I've not found anything.

---

It seems useful and simple enough that there must be a built-in. The closest I've come is this:

```
-- Eg.
get :: Read a => IO a
get = (liftM read) getLine

main = do
        x <- get
        print $ x + 5
```

Comment: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Read+a+%3D%3EIO+a

Comment: @JoshLee Oh... whoops, I guess I should have checked if adding the `Read` constraint on hoogle helped. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, usually `fmap` is preferable to `liftM`, since it's more general.

Comment: Or infix fmap: `read <$> getLine`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [`readLn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readLn):

```
readLn :: Read a => IO a
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for (can't accept for another few minutes).

Comment: ...and this is better than `liftM read getLine` because it turns parse errors into `IO` exceptions that happen immediately instead of pure exceptions that are delayed to the use site of the `a` value.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that `readLn` calls `readIO` in order to raise an `IO` exception instead of undefined.

```
Prelude> x <- (fmap read getLine) :: IO Integer 
asdf
Prelude> x
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse

Prelude> x <- (readIO =<< getLine) :: IO Integer 
asdf
*** Exception: user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse)
```